# tensorflow with scikeras.wrappers KerasRegressor returning ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, scikeras

I'm trying to model a DNN for the California housing dataset within sklearn using tensorflow. To define hyperparameters I would like to use gridsearchCV but encountering

```
ValueError: Could not interpret metric identifier: loss
```

The actual compiling of the model seems to work as all epochs are being finished.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# load and prepare data
housing = fetch_california_housing()
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target, random_state=42)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full, random_state=42)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid = scaler.transform(X_valid)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)


def build_model(layers, units, learning_rate):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    
    for _ in range(1, layers):
        model.add(Dense(units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

# KerasRegressor-Wrapper
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model, epochs=20, verbose=1, learning_rate=0.001, layers=3, units=64)

# Para-Grid 
param_grid = {
    'layers': [3],
    'units': [64],
    'learning_rate': [0.0001],
    'batch_size': [32],
}

# GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',error_score='raise')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```